# Trigger a lambda function by kinesis stream events cold boot issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a Java producer from client app which produces location data in real time, the data is then put into kinesis stream which will trigger a lambda function to process the data. The problem is, cold start time of the lambda is relatively slow. Setting up an event to invoke the lambda every 1 minute doesn’t really helps. Is using ec2 instead of lambda is the only way if I want a faster processing time?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it does work better now after i set up a concurrency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cold start issues, usual solution is to setup [provisioned concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html):

> By allocating provisioned concurrency before an increase in invocations, you can ensure that all requests are served by initialized instances with **low latency**.